# Retrieve data-descr attribute using jquery to use in Fancybox thumbnail

Tags: jquery, attributes, fancybox, fancybox-2

```
<div class="shirt-thumb">
    <a href="../wp-content/uploads/2014/05/icelandic-logo2.png" class="fancybox fancybox-thumb" rel="shirt1" title="shirt">
        <img src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/05/icelandic-logo2.png" data-descr="Shirt 1 Back" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Above is my HTML. What I am trying to do is grab that data-descr attribute and add it to the Fancybox thumbnail in jquery so that I can apply css to style it as an ::after element. I need the descriptions to appear below each thumbnail. From what I'm understanding, there isn't a built in way to do this, only apply the title underneath the fullsize image?

This is how the variables for the thumbnail list items are defined. The only one I actually added was thumbDescr, the other three came with Fancybox:

```
init: function (opts, obj) {
    var that = this,
        list,
        thumbDescr = opts.description,
        thumbWidth = opts.width,
        thumbHeight = opts.height,
        thumbSource = opts.source;
```

Below is the build of my thumbnail list item. This part loads fine:

```
for (var n = 0; n < obj.group.length; n++) {
    list += '<li><a style="width:' + thumbWidth + 'px;height:' + thumbHeight + 'px;" data-descr="' + thumbDescr + '" href="javascript:$.fancybox.jumpto(' + n + ');"></a></li>';
}
```

And these are things I have done to try to retrieve the description:

This basically just applied the function text to the data-descr instead of retrieving it -

```
description: function (item) { //function to obtain the description of the thumbnail image
    var descr;

    if (item.element) {
        descr = $(item.element).find('img').attr('data-descr');
    }

    if (!descr && item.type === 'image' && item.href) {
        descr = item.href;
    }

    return descr;
}
```

Same thing -

```
description: function (item) { // function to obtain the description of the thumbnail image
    var descr;

    if (item.element) {
        descr = $(item.element).find('img').data("descr"),
    }

    return descr;
}
```

And this returned "undefined" -

```
description : F.find('img').data("descr")
```

...where F was defined as the class .fancybox earlier in the jquery.

Yep, I'm pretty new at this, I'm sure there is an easy fix but I'm not sure how to find what I need. Please let me know if I didn't include enough info.

Comment: Do you want the description to appear below each thumbnail caption-style? how big will be your thumbnails? otherwise it may look crowded or unreadable

Comment: This is what the client wants, it's basically going to say the title of the thumb under the thumb. The thumbs are 80px wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are "*pretty new at this*", I wouldn't advise you to mess with the original fancybox js files. You could achieve pretty much anything you want within your own fancybox custom initialization using fancybox callbacks.

First, bear in mind that fancybox thumbnails helpers are appended after the (fancybox) image is shown on the screen, so in order to append the description/title (retrieved from the `data-descr` attribute of the `<img>` tag) you may need to use the `afterShow` callback.

Also, since there is a little delay in the process, it would be better to use `setTimeout()` function to make sure that the thumbnails have been fully appended to the DOM.

So try this code :

```
var _descrFlag = false;
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        thumbs: {
            width: 80, // your thumbnails size
            height: 80
        }
    },
    afterShow: function (current) {
        // validate if we already added the captions
        if (!_descrFlag) {
            // wait a bit
            setTimeout(function () {
                // get each data-descr
                $(".fancybox").each(function (i) {
                    // wrap data-descr in a html element
                    var _dataDescr = "<p>" + $(this).find("img").data("descr") + "</p>";
                    // append it to the current thumb using .eq()
                    $("#fancybox-thumbs").find("li").css({
                        backgroundColor: "#fff" // default is transparent so
                    }).eq(i).append(_dataDescr);
                }); // each
                // done? set flag to true
                _descrFlag = true;
            }, 100); // adjust time as needed
        }; // if
    }
}); // fancybox
```

**NOTES** :

- we used a `_descrFlag` variable flag (and validate it first in the callback) to make sure the descriptions are added only once.
- notice that we need to append a html element (`var _dataDescr`); in the example we used `<p>` but you can use any html element you need.
- if a `source` is not set, fancybox will create the thumbnails from the (big) image shown on the box. You can reduce the overhead and page load specifying the `source` of the thumbnail, which can be same as the `<img>` tag for instance, so you could do :

  ```
  helpers: {
      thumbs: {
          width: 80,
          height: 80,
          source: function (current) {
              return current.element.find("img").attr("src");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q2T2j/1/)**

... and no need to mess with the original js files ;)